# Freeing memory with a struct pointing to another struct

Tags: c, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have seen this topic a few times on here but couldn't quite find the information to help me out. I am trying to get better with freeing memory for my programming class. I have the below code to allocate some memory, but don't quite understand how to free it. I take the number of members, allocate that many members, then allocate the number of wines each member has rated, and store information for each wine they have rated in another struct linked through my member one.

How do I free memory for this specific style of program?

I commented out the printf statements for showing the information input into the program. Any help appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct wine {
    char type[20];
    char brand[20];
    int rating;
} wine;

typedef struct member {
    char name[20];
    int numRated;
    wine* list;
} member;

int main()
{
    int n;
    
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    member *members = malloc(n * sizeof(member));
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%s", (members+i)->name);
        scanf("%d", &(members+i)->numRated);
        (members+i)->list = malloc((members+i)->numRated * sizeof(wine));
        
        for(int j=0; j<(members+i)->numRated; j++){
            scanf("%s", (members+i)->list[j].type);
            scanf("%s", (members+i)->list[j].brand);
            scanf("%d", &(members+i)->list[j].rating);
            
        }
    }
    
    // for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    //     printf("%s: %d\n", (members+i)->name, (members+i)->numRated);
    //     for(int j=0; j<(members+i)->numRated; j++){
    //         printf("Type:%s  Brand: %s  Rating: %d\n", (members+i)->list[j].type, (members+i)->list[j].brand, (members+i)->list[j].rating);
    //     }
    //     printf("\n");
    // }

    

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Put in an explicit question.

Comment: There are n+1 frees required in this code: the  items you allocated in the loop, and the 1 item you allocated for members. In short, if you have a malloc/realloc/calloc/strdup, sooner or later you need a free to match it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes that is a valid way to put it. Is there any difference? This code isn't for turning in anywhere so just testing out a different way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right. But this is why I advocate just using array indexing, it's less confusing.

Comment: Back to your question, enumerate your sequence and free all the `list` members you allocated, then free the members sequence itself. I.e. the very n+1 allocations I mentioned before.

Comment: It's really very simple: Anything you malloc, you should later free. So if you do `(members+i)->list = malloc((members+i)->numRated * sizeof(wine));` you have to eventually `free((members+i)->list);`

Comment: I can show some attempts in a minute that I made. Attempts so far haven’t been very successful when trying to iterate through each wine for each member and freeing it individually.

Comment: Don't use `"%s"` in scanf.  It is no better than `gets`.  You must specify a maximum width on the conversion specifier.  eg `scanf("%19s", (members+i)->name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

At the bottom of your code, you would first free the wine ratings for each member and then free the member list itself:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    free(members[i].list); // Or free((members + i)->list;
}
free(members);
```

In general, you should have a matching call to `free` for each call to `malloc`.

### A little more explanation:

The first call to `malloc` allocates a single block of memory to hold `n` members' information. Even though this block of memory can store `n` members' information, it is still just a single block of memory and will be freed with a single call to free.

In your loop, you allocate a block of memory for each member (`n` times) that will store their wine ratings' information. Even if a member has many wine ratings, there is still just one block of memory for that member's wine ratings, so you'll need as many calls to `free` as there are members with wine ratings.

Also, notice how the calls to `free` happen in reverse order of the calls to `malloc`. This makes sense intuitively, you would want to free `members[i].list` before you free `members`.

Comment: I definitely overthought my initial attempts at freeing. Thank you for your answer.